# Geoserver WFS GetFeature - BoundingBox

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to produce a GetFeature-Request that takes into account a bbox parameter. It is a lokal geoserver (2.14.2, not able to upgrade it), so no possibility to reproduce for you, but maybe someone had a similar problem

If I use the following request, everything works fine:

http://host-310-1-fk:6081/geoserver/ALKIS_BB_vereinfacht/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ALKIS_BB_vereinfacht%3AFlurstueck&maxFeatures=50&srsName=EPSG:25833

According to the docs I should be able to add
&bbox=376900,5699600,376902,5699670 to the link and get the features inside said box. But I get an error:

```
org.geotools.factory.FactoryNotFoundException: Can't find a response parser factory for GET_FEATURE/'application/vnd.ogc.se_xml' Can't find a response parser factory for GET_FEATURE/'application/vnd.ogc.se_xml'
```

Is the way I pass the bbox to the geoserver wrong? Or is the problem lying beneath in the WFS that I am rerouting using my geoserver?

```
Request: getFeature
service = WFS
version = 1.0.0
baseUrl = http://host-310-1-fk:6081/geoserver/
query[0]:
    filter = [  bbox POLYGON ((376900 5699600, 376900 5699670, 376902 5699670, 376902 5699600, 376900 5699600)) ]
    srsName = EPSG:25833
    typeName[0] = {ALKIS_BB_vereinfacht}Flurstueck
maxFeatures = 50
outputFormat = GML2
resultType = results
```

> 2021-07-20 10:30:17,696 WARN [data.wfs] - Can't find a response parser factory for GET_FEATURE/'application/vnd.ogc.se_xml'
> 2021-07-20 10:30:17,696 ERROR [data.ows] - Failed to execute request https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/ows/alkis_vereinf_wfs?PROPERTYNAME=idflurst%2Cflstkennz%2Cland%2Clandschl%2Cgemarkung%2Cgemaschl%2Cflur%2Cflurschl%2Cflstnrzae%2Cflstnrnen%2Cregbezirk%2Cregbezschl%2Ckreis%2Ckreisschl%2Cgemeinde%2Cgmdschl%2Coid%2Caktualit%2Cgeometrie%2Cflaeche%2Cabwrecht%2Clagebeztxt%2Ctntxt&FILTER=%3Cogc%3AFilter+xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22+xmlns%3Agml%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%22+xmlns%3Aogc%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fogc%22%3E%3Cogc%3ABBOX%3E%3Cogc%3APropertyName%2F%3E%3Cgml%3AEnvelope+srsDimension%3D%222%22+srsName%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Fgml%2Fsrs%2Fepsg.xml%2325833%22%3E%3Cgml%3AlowerCorner%3E376900+5699600%3C%2Fgml%3AlowerCorner%3E%3Cgml%3AupperCorner%3E376902+5699670%3C%2Fgml%3AupperCorner%3E%3C%2Fgml%3AEnvelope%3E%3C%2Fogc%3ABBOX%3E%3C%2Fogc%3AFilter%3E&TYPENAME=ave%3AFlurstueck&REQUEST=GetFeature&RESULTTYPE=RESULTS&OUTPUTFORMAT=text%2Fxml%3B+subtype%3Dgml%2F3.1.1&VERSION=1.1.0&MAXFEATURES=50&SERVICE=WFS
> 2021-07-20 10:30:17,696 INFO [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.
> 2021-07-20 10:30:17,696 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -
> org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException:  error:org.geotools.factory.FactoryNotFoundException: Can't find a response parser factory for GET_FEATURE/'application/vnd.ogc.se_xml'
> at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML2OutputFormat.encode(GML2OutputFormat.java:269)
> at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML2OutputFormat.write(GML2OutputFormat.java:279)
> at org.geoserver.wfs.WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.write(WFSGetFeatureOutputFormat.java:185)
> at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1032)
> at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:268)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
> at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
> at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
> at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
> at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
> at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:90)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.geotools.factory.FactoryNotFoundException: Can't find a response parser factory for GET_FEATURE/'application/vnd.ogc.se_xml'
> at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
> at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
> at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$Task.run(TransformerBase.java:284)
> at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:119)
> at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase.transform(TransformerBase.java:101)
> at org.geoserver.wfs.xml.GML2OutputFormat.encode(GML2OutputFormat.java:259)
> ... 89 more
> Caused by: org.geotools.factory.FactoryNotFoundException: Can't find a response parser factory for GET_FEATURE/'application/vnd.ogc.se_xml'
> at org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSExtensions.findResponseFactory(WFSExtensions.java:96)
> at org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSRequest.createResponse(WFSRequest.java:200)
> at org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSRequest.createResponse(WFSRequest.java:36)
> at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.internalIssueRequest(AbstractOpenWebService.java:446)
> at org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSClient.internalIssueRequest(WFSClient.java:313)
> at org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSClient.issueRequest(WFSClient.java:353)
> at org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(WFSFeatureSource.java:260)
> at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getReader(ContentFeatureSource.java:610)
> at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:164)
> at org.geoserver.feature.RetypingFeatureCollection.features(RetypingFeatureCollection.java:45)
> at org.geoserver.feature.RetypingFeatureCollection.features(RetypingFeatureCollection.java:45)
> at org.geoserver.feature.RetypingFeatureCollection.features(RetypingFeatureCollection.java:31)
> at org.geotools.data.crs.ForceCoordinateSystemFeatureResults.openIterator(ForceCoordinateSystemFeatureResults.java:93)
> at org.geotools.feature.collection.AbstractFeatureCollection.features(AbstractFeatureCollection.java:66)
> at org.geotools.feature.collection.DecoratingSimpleFeatureCollection.features(DecoratingSimpleFeatureCollection.java:89)
> at org.geotools.gml.producer.FeatureTransformer$FeatureTranslator.encode(FeatureTransformer.java:578)
> at org.geotools.xml.transform.TransformerBase$XMLReaderSupport.parse(TransformerBase.java:996)
> at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(Unknown Source)

After Switching to Post:

> 2021-07-20 14:25:35,534 INFO [geoserver.wfs] -
> Request: getServiceInfo
> 2021-07-20 14:25:35,690 ERROR [data.ows] - Failed to execute request https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/ows/alkis_vereinf_wfs?REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS
> 2021-07-20 14:25:35,690 ERROR [geoserver.ows] -
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/ows/alkis_vereinf_wfs?REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS
> at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getAbsoluteSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:330)
> at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:297)
> at org.geotools.data.store.ContentDataStore.getSchema(ContentDataStore.java:293)
> at org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingDataStore.updateMap(RetypingDataStore.java:214)
> at org.geoserver.feature.retype.RetypingDataStore.getSchema(RetypingDataStore.java:117)
> at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getFeatureSource(ResourcePool.java:1260)
> at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.FeatureTypeInfoImpl.getFeatureSource(FeatureTypeInfoImpl.java:128)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor449.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:128)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.getFeatureSource(Unknown Source)
> at org.geoserver.wfs.GetFeature.run(GetFeature.java:579)
> at org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService.getFeature(DefaultWebFeatureService.java:105)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor556.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
> at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:50)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.getFeature(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor555.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:877)
> at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:264)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
> at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
> at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
> at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
> at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
> at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:90)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/ows/alkis_vereinf_wfs?REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
> at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
> at org.geotools.data.ows.SimpleHttpClient$SimpleHTTPResponse.(SimpleHttpClient.java:169)
> at org.geotools.data.ows.SimpleHttpClient.post(SimpleHttpClient.java:132)
> at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.internalIssueRequest(AbstractOpenWebService.java:438)
> at org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSClient.internalIssueRequest(WFSClient.java:313)
> at org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSClient.issueRequest(WFSClient.java:374)
> at org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStore.getRemoteFeatureType(WFSDataStore.java:206)
> at org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStore.getRemoteSimpleFeatureType(WFSDataStore.java:262)
> at org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSFeatureSource.buildFeatureType(WFSFeatureSource.java:364)
> at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getAbsoluteSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:328)
> ... 113 more

Thanks

Edit:
So after chatting with the guys that set up the WFS, I got it working in postman where I used a POST request with an added body in format RAW.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:adv="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0" xmlns:fg="http://www.interactive-instruments.de/ns/aaa/flurgema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:gml32="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" outputFormat="text/xml; subtype=gml/3.2.1" resultType="results">
    <wfs:Query typeName="ave:Flurstueck" xmlns:ave="http://repository.gdi-de.org/schemas/adv/produkt/alkis-vereinfacht/2.0">
        <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:BBOX> 
                <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833" srsDimension="2"> 
                    <gml:lowerCorner>332590 5807162</gml:lowerCorner> 
                    <gml:upperCorner>332807 5807263</gml:upperCorner> 
                </gml:Envelope> 
            </ogc:BBOX> 
        </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>                  
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

Is it possible to change the geoserver GetFeature-Request to be of that kind?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Thank you, I neither know if I got the right level nor if it is the "relevant" part of the log file as I am kinda lost, but I updated my question with the request that fails and the error shown in the geoserver logs.

Comment: is this a cascaded WFS request?

Comment: Yes it is a cascaded wfs

Comment: So, basically the remote WFS is returning an error about your bounding box? You may need to raise a bug report with details of the remote service and the request you are making to GeoServer

Comment: Ok thanks for that insight, I was not sure if this is about my geoserver setup or the service I am rerouting. Seems like I have to raise a request there. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's had to be completly sure but when I decode your URL (and to be honest I would switch to POST at this point) I get the following for your filter:

```
<ogc:Filter xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
  <ogc:BBOX>                                                                                                            
    <ogc:PropertyName/>                                                                                                 
    <gml:Envelope srsDimension="2" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#25833">                             
      <gml:lowerCorner>376900 5699600</gml:lowerCorner>                                                                 
      <gml:upperCorner>376902 5699670</gml:upperCorner>                                                                 
    </gml:Envelope>                                                                                                     
  </ogc:BBOX>                                                                                                           
</ogc:Filter>
```

So, I expect you need to specify which `PropertyName` your geometry is in.

Comment: Thanks, If I switch to post (I checked "Favor HTTP POST method over GET" in the Edit Vector Data Source) I get an error/a service-exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/ows/alkis_vereinf_wfs?REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400

Comment: Where would I specify the PropertyName?

Comment: inside the `<ogc:PropertyName>....</ogc:PropertyName>` pair

Comment: Hi @Ian Turton, I updated the question after having a chat with the guys that set up the WFS. Is it possible to tell geoserver how to use the information?